# Andy Android Emulator Windows 8 issue

Tags: android-emulator

About a month ago, I loaded the Android emulator "Andy" on my windows 8 laptop and it seemed to work fine (except it kept kicking me out of Clash of Clans after a couple minutes, but the emulator kept running).

Yesterday, something happened.  While in Clash of Clans, the background turned all black and just the small images were visible.  This has happened before and I would kill Andy using the X in the upper right corner.  I would then restart Andy and things worked OK again.

However, yesterday when this happened, I killed Andy in the same way, but when I tried to restart Andy the frame would display for a second or two and then go away.

I figured that a bit got twisted somewhere, so I uninstalled that version of Andy and downloaded and installed a newer version, but I get the same results.

I checked the web and the closest I came was "Andy won't launch on windows 8".  The suggested solution was to roll back the display driver.  I did that with the same results.

I figure that there may be a flag somewhere that thinks Andy is running, so it shuts down any new version, but that is just a guess.

Has anyone else run into this problem?
If so what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the compatibility setting to windows 7/8